Getting worse results when binary cross-entropy loss is computed from logits in Keras
My model (Keras framework) performs significantly worse when the loss is calculated from logits:
model = keras.Sequential([
    keras.Input((input.shape[-1],)),
    keras.layers.BatchNormalization(),
    keras.layers.Dense(50, activation="relu"),
    keras.layers.BatchNormalization(),
    keras.layers.Dense(1),
])
model.compile(optimizer=keras.optimizers.Adam(), loss=keras.losses.BinaryCrossentropy(from_logits=True), metrics=["auc"])

compared with when the activation function is in the classification layer:
model = keras.Sequential([
    keras.Input((input.shape[-1],)),
    keras.layers.BatchNormalization(),
    keras.layers.Dense(50, activation="relu"),
    keras.layers.BatchNormalization(),
    keras.layers.Dense(1, activation="sigmoid"),
])
model.compile(optimizer=keras.optimizers.Adam(), loss=keras.losses.BinaryCrossentropy(), metrics=["auc"])

And this is the only change I make.
Does anybody have any idea why this happens? From what I know, calculating loss from logits is as accurate in most and more accurate in some instances, it shouldn't perform worse. Here are the metric charts for the two models (every run gives similar results, ~73.5 auc vs ~76.5 auc): from logits, sigmoid in last layer

It really shouldn't make a difference, you may have just gotten unlucky with weight initializations or other random factors. Is this reproducible? Ideally you would provide a minimal reproducible example here including a toy dataset where this happens consistently.

@xdurch0 yeah it's the same every time. Here's the data: https://mega.nz/file/XFRzDSib#pRHaIBLrKLLk9dY9KT2II_Af8xuutbFtr2rXgQ5S94Y

The reason why are you getting different results when you use same loss
function and metrics is due to (from_logits = True) in your loss function.If
you use activation function in the last layer you will get the same values
for loss and metrics .i have execute code with different cases please refer
to this gist.
